# How to start text from where my button begins and i don't want to flow it outside?

Tags: html, css, web, new-operator

I am new to coding and was working on this for three day and unable to solve this problem in my code
I want to start the text inside button from exactly where button start from left side and I dont want it to flow outside
Please help
Thanks in advance

```html
    <style>
        .container {
            margin: 0 auto;
            /* this will center the page */
            width: 70%;
            /*  width here */
        }
        
        .column {
            float: left;
            width: auto;
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }
        
        .square {
            height: 390px;
            width: 290px;
            background-color: #22262e;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        
        .button {
            border-radius: 4px;
            width: 34%;
            background-color: #2c7f40;
            /* Green */
            border: none;
            color: white; /* Text color in button */
            font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
            padding: 4% 30%;
            text-align: left;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 20px;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            cursor: pointer;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
            /* Safari */
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Button in Box Project</h2>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="square"> <br>
                <center><a href="https://www.duckduckgo.com" class="button">T</a></center>
            </div>
        </div>

 


        

    </div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't set a `padding` if you don't want it

Comment: Wow thank you very much and damn it was that easy lol

Comment: Or, if you only want the left padding to be 0: `padding: 4% 30% 4% 0;`

Comment: Recommended site: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
            margin: 0 auto;
            /* this will center the page */
            width: 70%;
            /*  width here */
        }
        
        .column {
            float: left;
            width: auto;
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }
        
        .square {
            height: 390px;
            width: 290px;
            background-color: #22262e;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        
        .button {
            border-radius: 4px;
            width: auto;
            background-color: #2c7f40;
            /* Green */
            border: none;
            color: white; /* Text color in button */
            font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
            padding: 5px 0px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 20px;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            cursor: pointer;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
            /* Safari */
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
            position : relative;
            overflow-wrap: break-word;
            line-height: 2em;
            max-width : 100%;
            display: inline-block;
            
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="square"><br>
                <a href="https://www.duckduckgo.com" class="button">Hello , Hello </a>
                <a href="https://www.duckduckgo.com" class="button">Hello</a>
                <a href="https://www.duckduckgo.com" class="button">Hello , Hello</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little what you changed?

Comment: Also, `padding: 4%;` will not start the text from the most left position

Comment: @brombeer padding and overflow-wrap this my change And a few other changes `padding` : This is why you do not move from left to right and from 5px up and down
`overflow-wrap` : Do not pull content out of the button